# How to get Tweets by keyword and hashtag for specific user?(PHP API)

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I need to get tweets based on specific keyword and hashtag for a specific user.

for example, if we search "user= @test; hashtag= hiphop". So, any @test tweets will appear in the feed, and any time the hashtag #hiphop is used, those tweets will be pulled in as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Using the q parameter, read : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators

Comment: Thanks for your response.

How can we define screen_name in q parameter?

Could you please give me one example for getting tweet by keyword for specific user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweets from @test containing #hiphop or hipop, using the `q` parameter :

`from:@test (#hiphop OR hipop)`

(a space is an `AND`)